# SQL named range in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, excel, database, vba, sqlite

Is there a way I can use a named range as part of the WHERE clause in the strSQL line?

I have a named range Cell M1 on Sheet2 is called Code. I would like to have instead of having to hardcode the Ticker symbol in the WHERE clause.

I have tried doing 'Code' and [Sheet2].[Code] Both returned errors.

```
Set TestData = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.Open "DRIVER=SQLITE3 ODBC DRIVER;DATABASE=C:\Users\jez\financials.db;"

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM financials WHERE Ticker='AAPL' "

TestData.Open strSQL, conn

For icols = 0 To TestData.Fields.Count - 1
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, icols + 1).Value = TestData.Fields(icols).Name
Next icols

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset TestData
TestData.Close

Set TestData = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing


End Sub
```

UPDATE

Doing the following:

```
Dim code As Range

Set code = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("M1")
Dim r As Variant
r = code.Value
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM financials WHERE Ticker= 'r'"
```

Doesn't give an error and it will produce the headers from the database but it fails to produce any values.

Comment: `strSQL = "SELECT * FROM financials WHERE Ticker = '" & r & "'"`

Comment: @DougGlancy Thanks! So we have to use the ' because the code name needs to have " around it?

Comment: Yes, the string in the SQL has to have single-quotes around it. The you can view `strSQL` in VBA's Immediate Window (ctrl-G) with `? strSQL`. The result will be something like your original hardcoded example: `SELECT * FROM financials WHERE Ticker = 'ML'`